# SERVLET - HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
 <form action="MyServlet">
  <input type="submit" value="Get Count">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyServlet.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet  {

    private String mymsg;
    //private String message;
    int  hc;

       public void init() throws ServletException {
          mymsg = "Hello World!";
          hc=0;
          //message = "Hey";
       }

       public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
          HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException 
       {

          // Setting up the content type of webpage
          response.setContentType("text/html");

          // Writing message to the web page
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.println("<h1>" + mymsg + "</h1>");
          out.println("Count: ");
          out.println(hc++);
       }

       public void destroy() {
          
       }
    }
```

## **When i run this im getting the error:**

HTTP Status 405 – Method Not Allowed

Type Status Report

Message HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

===================================================

**i dont understand why because im only using get method and not using post at all...Please help**

Comment: Try adding `method="get"` to the `<input>` or `<form>` element.  (Not sure why it would be necessary since the HTML spec says that the default method is a `GET`.)

Comment: What server runtime was this?

Comment: You're not running the code you think you're running. Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In that servlet corresponding POST method handling is not implemented.
To solve this overriding the below method from HttpServlet,

`void javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException`

Sample code,

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MyServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet  {

private String mymsg;
//private String message;
int  hc;

   public void init() throws ServletException {
      mymsg = "Hello World!";
      hc=0;
      //message = "Hey";
   }

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException 
   {

      // Setting up the content type of webpage
      response.setContentType("text/html");

      // Writing message to the web page
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      out.println("<h1>" + mymsg + "</h1>");
      out.println("Count: ");
      out.println(hc++);
   }

   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
      doGet(request, response);
   }
   public void destroy() {
      
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-submission-attributes:invalid-value-default and https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-method say `get` is the default.

Comment: Sorry, have checked the default method is post. After setting the method="post" issue is reproducible.